# What is the System() import in Python

Tags: python, jython

Long story short, a piece of code that I'm working with at work has the line:

```
from System                               import System
```

with a later bit of code of:

```
desc_          = System()
xmlParser = Parser(desc_.getDocument()) 
# xmlParser.setEntityBase(self.dtdBase)
for featureXMLfile in featureXmlList.split(","):
    print featureXMLfile
    xmlParser.parse(featureXMLfile)
feat   = desc_.get(featureName)
return feat
```

`Parser` is an XML parser in Java (it's included in a different import), but I don't get what the `desc_` bit is doing. I mean obviously, it somehow holds the feature that we're trying to pull out, but I don't entirely see where. Is `System` a standard library in Python or Java, or am I looking at something custom?

Unfortunately, everyone else in my group is out for Christmas Eve vacation, so I can't ask them directly. Thank you for your help. I'm still not horribly familiar with Python.

Comment: What does Java have to do with anything?

Comment: Also, if you do `import System; print(System)`, it will tell you the path the module was loaded from. That should tell you if it's custom or not.

Comment: @millimoose I mainly wanted to be certain I wasn't omitting an important clue since I know that at least three imported modules are from Java. Which... I just realized I forgot to mention we're using Jython.

Comment: this might help: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2002/04/11/jythontips.html

Comment: @millimoose Thank you for the suggestion of using `import`. That did it. :) If you want to post it as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

millimoose indicated the correct answer in his comment, but neglected to submit it as an answer, so I'm posting to indicate the correct answer. It was indeed a custom module built by my company. I was able to determine this by typing `import System; print(System)` into the interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't from the standard library, so you'll need to check your system (Python has plenty of introspection to help you with that).

You can tell as Python modules in the standard library use lowercase names [as per PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), or by searching [the library reference](http://docs.python.org/3/library/).

Note as well that Python has it's own [XML](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) [parsing](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/xml.sax.reader.html) [tools](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/xml.dom.html) that will be much nicer to work with in Python than Java's.

Edit: As you have noted in the comments you are using Jython, it seems likely this is Java's `System` package.

Comment: Following millimoose's suggestion above, I found that it is actually a custom module with my company. I thank you for your answer, though.